# Python 3.3: Recursive version of a function

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

```
def abc(s):
    filter = [i for i in s.lower() if i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
    for i in range(len(filter) - 1):
        if filter[i] > filter[i+1]:
            return print(s, "is not abcdearian")
    return print(s,  "is abcdearian")


while True:
    try:
        s = input("String? ")
abc(s)
```

I'am having trouble making a recursive version of abc(s). Any ideas?

Comment: wouldn't recursion be more like `def abc(s): ... abc(subs)... return` ? Specifically, I mean, for recursion you would need to call the function with some other argument inside its own body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-recursive solution:

```
def issorted(L):
    return all(x <= y for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))
```

To make a recursive function you should find a way to split the problem into smaller and/or simpler subproblems that could be solve the same way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from string import ascii_lowercase

def abcdearian(s):
    return issorted_recursive([c for c in s.lower() if c in ascii_lowercase])

def issorted_recursive(L):
    return L[0] <= L[1] and issorted_recursive(L[1:]) if len(L) > 1 else True
```

Here `issorted_recursive()` is a recursive function. The base case is `len(L) <= 1` (a list with zero or one element is always sorted so return `True` in this case). In the recursive case (`len(L) > 1`) the list `L` is considered sorted if the first item is in the sorted order (`L[0] <= L[1]`) *and* the rest of the list (`L[1:]`) is also sorted. Each time the function receives smaller and smaller input until out of order element is found (`L[0] > L[1]`) or the base case is encountered and the function finishes.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/MG3mSL)

```
while True:
    s = input("String? ")
    if not s:
        break
    print("{} is {}abcdearian".format(s, "" if abcdearian(s) else "not "))
```

#### Input

```
    abc
    bac
```

#### Output

```
String? abc is abcdearian
String? bac is not abcdearian
String?
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your answer is spot on.

Comment: As this was originally written, I thought the first "issorted" was part of the recursive solution, and was being called at each step of the recursion. (I didn't read carefully: I just saw that the answer was complicated.)  I've submitted an edit that makes it clear that these are TWO ALTERNATIVE IMPLEMENTATIONS of "issorted". One with recursion, one without. (If this had been done in the first place, I would have read the answer correctly, and not wasted my time writing a "simpler" solution, because I would have realized this WAS a simple solution!)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: I've moved non-recursive solution into a separate code code example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's equivalent to the one posted in the question, but written in a recursive style:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def abc(s):
    f = [c for c in s.lower() if c in ascii_lowercase]
    if aux(f, 0):
        return s + " is abcdearian"
    else:
        return s + " is not abcdearian"

def aux(s, i):
    if i >= len(s)-1:
        return True
    elif s[i] > s[i+1]:
        return False
    else:
        return aux(s, i+1)
```

Use it like this:

```
while True:
    s = input("String? ")
    if not s:
        break
    print(abc(s))
```

Notice that I split the problem in two: first the, "main" function `abc()` takes care of filtering the string, calling the `aux` procedure with correct initial values and returning the result string at the end (alternatively: you could have returned a boolean, creating the result string elsewhere.)

The real work is done in the helper `aux` function, which recursively traverses the string checking if the "abcdearian" condition is true for all pairs of consecutive characters in the string. The way `aux` iterates over the string is efficient (putting aside the fact that we're using recursion), because it never creates additional intermediate strings with `s[1:]`. It's also an example of a [tail-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/201359) algorithm, and it closely mirrors the structure of the iterative solution.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian on second thought ... why exactly isn't equivalent? can you provide a counterexample, please?

Comment: there is no `lowercase` in Python 3.3. You could use ascii_lowercase. Also `abc()` should return a boolean for proper separation of concern.

Comment: there is no guarantee that codepoints are in alphabetical order for non-ascii letters (str.isalpha() operates on Unicode strings in Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

The way the accepted answer was originally written, it seemed to be overly complex. I've submitted an edit that hopefully fixes that. But by the time I realized that, I had already written the below answer and explanation. Keeping it, in case the explanation is useful to someone:

```
def abc(s):
    filtered = [i for i in s.lower() if i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
    optionalNotString = ('' if _abc(filtered) else ' not')
    print( '{0} is{1} abcdearian'.format( repr(s), optionalNotString ) )

# Recursively process the "rest" (remainder) of the string.
# At each step, examine the first two characters.
def _abc(rest):
    if len(rest) < 2:
        # We've successfully compared all successive pairs, so return True.
        return True
    if (rest[0] > rest[1]):
        return False
    return _abc(rest[1:])
```

In use (the most important cases to test, including too-short strings, and detecting a False condition at the end of string 'acb', as well as at start of string 'bac'. I had a bug the first way I wrote it, which failed to catch 'bac' as False!):

```
abc( '' )
abc( 'a' )
abc( 'ac' )
abc( 'abc' )
abc( 'acb' )
abc( 'bac' )
```

Output:

```
'' is abcdearian
'a' is abcdearian
'ac' is abcdearian
'abc' is abcdearian
'acb' is not abcdearian
'bac' is not abcdearian
```

Explanation:

1. The filtering only needs to be done once, so do it in the main "abc" function, not in the recursive "_abc" function.
2. At each step, the algorithm needs to look at two adjacent characters. In each call to "_abc", these will be the first two characters.
3. "_abc" needs to handle two cases:

   - Case 1: The string is too short to perform a comparison. E.g. '' or 'a'. Such strings satisfy the abcderian criterion, so return True.
   - Case 2: The string is at least two characters. Perform the abcderian calculation of the first two. If that fails, the answer is False. Otherwise, recurse with all but the first character.
4. "repr(s)" is an easy way to get "s" to print with its surrounding quotes.
5. "optionalNotString ": The desired answer string in the True/False cases only differs by the presence/absence of ' not'. So use "if .. else .." expression, to control whether ' not' is include in the formatted output. When not wanted, substitute the empty string ''.

Comment: BTW, I just re-read the accepted answer. I thought is was overkill, because of the use of zip in "issorted(L)". I thought that was being called as part of the answer, at each step of the iteration. That function should NOT have been part of the solution code; it shows an ALTERNATIVE to doing recursion. On re-reading his solution, "issorted_recursive(L)" does all the work, and does it in a pythonic way. But I'll leave my answer here, in case the explanation is useful to someone.